# how to refactor string.contains logic

Tags: c#

I have inherited some code that upon first glance smells funny, but perhaps I'm reading into it... while reviewing the code I came across the following and made a note to consider refactoring the logic as I found it difficult to read and prone to errors.

```
if (somestring.Contains("some value")
    result.add(specificString)
if (somestring.Contains("some other value")
    result.add(anotherSpecificString)
if (...)
```

... 100's of lines...

My questions are:

1. Is the pattern okay as it is? At a minimum, I feel this should be reduced to a method that accepts the possible values and their replacements instead of the repeated if logic?
2. Where is the 'breaking point' - what I mean, how many if.. checks are okay before it is better to refactor?
3. What other refactors would be a good match for this pattern?

I had some vague early thoughts about somehow using pattern matching, but that does not appear to be a good fit here?

Ultimately, I think I need to take a giant step back and come back to look at this objectively...

Comment: This question is probably better suited to <https://codereview.stackexchange.com/>.

Comment: you could make a struct that holds both search term and result value, and then just loop them against the `somestring`

Comment: @JoeSewell  when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the code above would likely be closed as off-topic because it [is missing context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652).

Comment: fair point @JoeSewell, thank you.

Comment: You could refactor it as Dimitry suggested but also, why? Is it great? No. Is it working? Hopefully. Do you want to risk changing/rewriting something just because it is a bit rubbish? It also begs a much larger question related to excessive use of strings which would bother me more than a load of if statements. If the real intent is understood, you might find a pattern specifically to solve it.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I'll keep that in mind in the future, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest extracting a model, e.g.

```
 // Model: when "find" is found we should add "add" to result
 static List<(string find, string add)> m_ToAdd = 
   new List<(string find, string add)>() {
     ("some value", specificString),
     ("some other value", anotherSpecificString),
      //TODO: Add more pairs here 
 };
```

then you can put it as a simple loop:

```
foreach (var pair in m_ToAdd)
  if (somestring.Contains(pair.find))
    result.add(pair.add);
```

Answers:

- Q1. Is the (existing) pattern okay as it is?
- A1. It can be tolerated if you are not going to add / remove `if`s and if you have few `if`s
- Q2. Where is the 'breaking point' - what I mean, how many `if`.. checks are okay before it is better to refactor?
- A2. My rule of thumb is 4-5 `if`s.
- Q3. What other refactors would be a good match for this pattern?
- A3. Model extraction: you have *data* (here it's `List<(string find, syting add)>`) and *logics* (`foreach` loop) separated.

Comment: Why not to use dictionary?

Comment: @Guru Stron: it may appear that `somestring` contains *several* `find`s and we may want to have *order preserved* (i.e. we may want to add `specificString` and only then `anotherSpecificString` if both `"some value"` and `"some other value"` are found). Dictionary doesn't guarantee any order. If order of `result.add` doesn't matter, `Dictionary<string, string>` will do

Comment: Sorry, misread `Contains` part for some reason) Using dictionary makes no sense here for sure)